# Python RabbitMQ and kombu: heartbeats

Tags: python, twisted, rabbitmq, kombu

I have a Twisted application (Python 2.7) that uses the kombu module to communicate with a RabbitMQ message server.

We're having problems with closing connections (probably firewall related) and I'm trying to implement the `heartbeat_check()` method to handle this. I've got a heartbeat value of 10 set on the connection and I've got a Twisted `LoopingCall` that calls the `heartbeat_check(rate=2)` method every 5 seconds.

However, once things get rolling I'm getting an exception thrown every other call to `heartbeat_check()` (based on the logging information I've got in the function that `LoopingCall` calls, which includes the call to `heartbeat_check`). I've tried all kinds of variations of heartbeat and rate values and nothing seems to help. When I debug into the `heartbeat_call()` it looks like some minor message traffic is being sent back and forth, am I supposed to respond to that in my message consumer?

Comment: This question is very difficult to answer, due in part to two things.  You've alluded to two potential problems - one about connections closing and one about exceptions - and you didn't describe either in much detail (for example, you didn't even say *what* exception is raised).  Try including more details about the problems and be clear about what behavior you're trying to change and what you're trying to change it to.  That will make it a lot easier for someone to lend a hand!

Comment: Jean-Paul, sorry about the ambiguity. The Twisted part of the application is performing well, it was the heartbeats exceptions that was confusing me. In this case the exception was "Too many missed heartbeats", which was being raised by Kombu. It turns out it was an internal problem with Kombu that we fixed another way, and submitted a patch back to the project.

Comment: I wonder if this question was resolved in a way that means it will never get an answer. On that basis I recommend it is closed as "Typo", as that can be used for unresolveable problems as well.